# indexing current value in for loop? Python

Tags: python

So I have a for loop.

```
>>> row = [5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2]
>>> for i in row:
    if i == 5:
        print(row.index(i))
    if i == 2:
        print(row.index(i))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
1
```

I want to get: `0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9`.
In other words, I want to get the index of the `i` I'm currently looking at in the `for` loop, if it is = 5 or 2... any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to produce a running index:

```
for index, i in enumerate(row):
    if i == 5:
        print(index)
    if i == 2:
        print(index)
```

or simpler still:

```
for index, i in enumerate(row):
    if i in (2, 5):
        print(index)
```

Comment: Ding ding ding, we have a winner in the 33rd second :)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, an alternative if one didn't want to use `enumerate` for some reason:

```
row = [5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2]
indices = filter(lambda idx: row[idx] in (5,2), xrange(len(row)))
# [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or as a list-comp:

```
indices = [idx for idx in xrange(len(row)) if row[idx] in (5, 2)]
```